# Как посчитать уникальные элементы в столбце и передавать их в другие столбы по условию

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Знатоки, просьба помочь с решением задачи.

Есть 3 столбца: дата, заказы и статус заказа. Заказы иногда повторяются, для каждого из них есть 5 разных статусов в отдельном столбце. Нужно создать таблицу: дата, заказ создан (для заказов со статусом placed, заказ отменен (для заказов со статусом cancel). Заказы не должны повторяться/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно - создавайте. А вопрос-то какой?

Comment: Не пойму в какую сторону копать, чтобы из той таблице, что на скрине, получить таблицу: Дата, заказ создан (количество уникальных заказов со статусом place_order, заказ отменен (количество уникальных заказов со статусом canceled).

Возможно с помощью join. Но четкого понимания нет

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date,
       SUM(IF(status = 'placed', 1, 0)) AS placed_count,
       SUM(IF(status = 'cancel', 1, 0)) AS canceled_count
FROM source_table
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date
```

В синтаксисе clickhouse не уверен, но идея именно такая.

> мне же нужно посчитать количество уникальных значений в столбце order_id

Попробуйте, съест ли clickhouse такую конструкцию:

```
SELECT date,
       COUNT(DISTINCT IF(status = 'placed', order_id, NULL)) AS placed_unique_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT IF(status = 'cancel', order_id, NULL)) AS canceled_unique_count
FROM source_table
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date
```

Comment: В данном случае мы пересчитаем значения столбца status (на деле action), мне же нужно посчитать количество уникальных значений в столбце order_id с 2 разными статусами в столбце action (place_order и canceled)

Comment: @ИванИванов Добавил ещё версию. Попробуйте.

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ ВАМ СПАСИБО! Все получилось!